# Android Studio Upload APK progress

Tags: android, android-studio, android-shell

Is it possible to view the upload progress of your apk to the device in Android Studio?

```
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.mycompany.myapp
```

I know it is possible using the command line

```
adb push -p
```